# Filter messages by subject long list

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-filter

What I'm trying to do is, I have a notification set up whenever there's a warning or any message on one of my servers, but they're both Unix and Windows, and I want to separate them by UX/WIN. I cannot amend the notification body or subject, so only way that I can think of is to filter them by hostname.

There's about 350 Windows servers, and around 250 Unix. Can I feed the filter a csv file or something like that, or do I have to spell out all the hostnames like: "hostname1", "hostname2", "...". Or will that even work ?

Thank you in advance,
P.

Comment: Based on the search, this thread may be helpful to you:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390852/how-to-filter-by-host-name-in-wireshark

Comment: Haven't received your message for a long time. Do you have any update?